# Insertar datos a una tabla con el mismo primary key

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net, vb.net

Buenas, estoy haciendo una pantalla donde almaceno los pagos de unos clientes, al momento de hacer el insert debo poner el mismo codigo de clientes. Debo usar el mismo id de cliente que es el primary key el cual me daba error. Pude arreglarlo haciendo un procedure pero ahora no me guarda nada y no me devuelve error.

Acá el procedure

```
ALter procedure SP_InsPagosMa3
    @CodigoCliente VARCHAR (10),
    @CodigoBanco VARCHAR(2),
    @MontoTotal float,
    @NumPago varchar(20),
    @FechaPago datetime,
    @FechaRegistro datetime

AS
BEGIN
INSERT INTO PagosManuales (CodigoCliente,CodigoBanco, MontoTotal, NumeroPago,FechaPago,FechaRegistro)
SELECT

     CodigoCliente = @CodigoCliente,
    CodigoBanco=@CodigoBanco,
    MontoTotal=@MontoTotal,
    NumeroPago=@NumPago,
    FechaPago=@FechaPago,
    FechaRegistro=@FechaRegistro

From [CobrosDirectos].[dbo].[PagosManuales]
 WHERE CodigoCliente = @CodigoCliente
END.
```

Código VB de mi función

```
Public Function IsnPago(ByVal CodigoCliente As String, ByVal CodigoBanco As String, ByVal MontoTotal As Double, ByVal NumPago As String, ByVal FechaPago As Date, ByVal FechaRegistro As Date) As String

    Dim cn As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
    Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
    Dim Resultado As String
    cn.ConnectionString = C.GetAppConfiguracion("CobroDirecto", "ConnCobroDirecto")
    Dim Str As String
    Str = ""
    cn.Open()

    Str = "EXEC SP_InsPagosMa3 CodigoCliente,@CodigoBanco,@MontoTotal,@NumPago,@FechaPago,@FechaRegistro"


    cmd = New SqlCommand(Str, cn)
    With cmd
        .Parameters.Add("@CodigoCliente", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 10).Value = CodigoCliente
        .Parameters.Add("@CodigoBanco", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 2).Value = CodigoBanco
        .Parameters.Add("@MontoTotal", Data.SqlDbType.Float).Value = MontoTotal
        .Parameters.Add("@NumPago", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 20).Value = NumPago
        .Parameters.Add("@FechaPago", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaPago
        .Parameters.Add("@FechaRegistro", Data.SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = FechaRegistro
        .ExecuteNonQuery()
    End With

    cn.Close()
    Resultado = "Pago aplicado"

    Return Resultado

End Function
```

Códido de cuando la llamo

```
protected Sub BtnAplica_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnAplica.Click


    Dim resultado As String
    Dim Seleccion As Boolean = False
    For Each RW As GridViewRow In Gvcobranzas.Rows
        If CType(RW.Cells(2).FindControl("CheckBox1"), CheckBox).Checked Then
            resultado = GM.IsnPago(TxtBuscarCli.Text, dlBnaco.SelectedValue, TxtPagoTotal.Text, TxtNuPago.Text, TxtFePago.Text, TxtFeReg.Text)
            Seleccion = True
            With lberror
                .Visible = True
                .Text = resultado
            End With
        Else
            With lberror
                .Visible = True
                .Text = "Favor de seleccionar las factura a pagar"
            End With
        End If
    Next
    CargaGridClientes()





End Sub
```

Comment: no se entiendo que estas preguntando. mira [ask]  para mejorar tu pregunta

Comment: Bajo ningún concepto puedes insertar más de una vez el mismo valor en un Primary Key. Para el caso de la tabla Clientes si debe ser su Clave Primaria el ID del cliente, pero para la factura debes tener el suyo propio que puede ser, por ejemplo, el número de factura. 

Con el modelo que tienes actualmente estás diciendo que un cliente solo puede tener una factura y en la vida real eso es un tanto imposible aunque cada caso es particular.

Comment: el cliente tendras varias facturas y debo poner cada una en filas diferente con su codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Por principio una primary key no debe repetirse, tal vez deberías plantear los datos en 2 diferentes tablas y unirlas mediante una llave foranea, una de tus tablas debería ser la tabla Clientes y otra más la tabla Pagos, donde la tabla Clientes quedaría como catálogo conteniendo los datos personales de los mismos y la tabla de Pagos usarias un ID propio del pago:

Ej.[image: Diagrama]

Comment: Quien creo la tabla lo puso como primary key y no tengo acceso a modificrla

Comment: esa tabla esta mal creada @neryad y no creo que puedas resolver el problema.